# Get data by specific field from Json file in Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript, service

The JSON file has following structure

```
localjson.json
  {
    "Product" :{
           "data" : [
               { "itemID" : "1" , "name" : "Apple" , "qty" : "3" }`,
               { "itemID" : "2" , "name" : "Banana" , "qty" : "10" } 
      ]

    } }
```

So get the item by id , the I have is

```
       getfruits(itemID: string) {
        return this.http.get<Array<Fruits>>('assets/localjson.json')
            .pipe(
               map((items: Array<any>) => {
              return items.find((item: Fruits) => {
               return item.itemID=== itemID;

             });
           })
              );
             }
```

Fruits.ts

```
    export class Fruits{
          itemID: string;
            name: string;
            qty: string;

     }
```

It says TypeError: items.find is not a function

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
export interface Fruits {
  itemID: string;
  name: string;
  qty: string;
}

getfruits(itemID: string) {
 return this.http.get<Array<Fruits>>('assets/localjson.json').pipe(
  map((items: { Product: { item: Fruits[] } }) => {
    return items.Product[0].find((item: Fruits) => {
      return item.itemID === itemID;
    });
  })
);
```

}

Comment: Hi, @Sayoooj , it might be silly questions, but did you  "item"  from JSON anywhere here ?

Comment: If the JSOn had 'data' instead of 'item', would there be any change in the function?

Comment: You can use hasOwnProperty() from object.prototype to check whether it has item or data key in the object